# creating new column with data filtering in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r that includes a numeric column.
I want to create a new column, which should contain a new value A if original is < 100 and a new value B if original is > 100.

Comment: Can you add some of your code to your question?

Comment: Yes. Please receive a selection from my data frame:                                         
    pais            varResp1 varResp2 "hosp"
1 Argentina    -5.42       22   hosp
2 Argentina    84.00       39   hosp
3 Argentina   -53.40       21   hosp
4 Argentina    59.87       29   hosp
5 Argentina   274.94       41   hosp
6 Argentina   140.62       10   hosp

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)

my_set = data.frame(x = rnorm(5, mean = 100))
#>          x
#> 1  99.49781
#> 2 100.13153
#> 3  99.92108
#> 4 100.88678
#> 5 100.11697

my_set %>% mutate(y = ifelse(x > 100, "A","B"))
#>           x y
#> 1 100.31863 A
#> 2  99.41821 B
#> 3 100.71453 A
#> 4  99.17474 B
#> 5  99.64014 B
```